# SwiftUI - Sheet presented from tab view pops to root view of a tab

Tags: swiftui

I need to have a sheet which when closed needs to return to the same view from which is opened and also transfer some information. Unfortunately for some reason the view is poped out when sheet is presented and the logic is broken. Here is MVP of the code:

```
@main
struct SmallApplication: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                TabView {
                    
                    TabbedView1()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Tab1", systemImage: "scanner")
                        }
                
                    TabbedView2()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Tab2", systemImage: "person")
                        }
                
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

struct TabbedView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("TabbedView1")
            .padding()
    }
}

struct TabbedView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            Text("TabbedView2")
            NavigationLink(
                "Go To View 3",
                destination: View3()
            )
        }
    }
}


struct View3: View {
    @State var presentSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            presentSheet = true
        } label: {
            Text("Click me")
        }.sheet(isPresented: $presentSheet, onDismiss: nil) {
            View4()
        }

    }
}


struct View4: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Pull down the sheet and see the result")
        }
    }
}
```

When you pull down the `sheet` it pops `Tab2` to `TabbedView2` instead of `View`. My question is why and how I can avoid that?

This happens only on iOS 15 but not on iOS 14.7 where everything works fine.
I use `TabView` inside `NavigationView` because this is the way to hide tab view in Detail View when needed.

Another option, that I'm having is to use `fullScreenCover` modifier (which works fine), but I prefer to use `sheet` for this task.

Edit: If you put application with opened `View3` on background, when opened `TabbedView2` is presented, which makes the problem really worse.

Comment: Looks like internal bug, submit feedback to Apple. (Btw, it navigates back right *before* sheet is presented, not on dismiss).

Comment: I will test with Xcode 13.2 first (I have very limited storage space) and then will submit a bug if needed. Thanks for the comment

Comment: I tested with Xcode 13.2.1 then wrote comment, so it is there.

Comment: BTW, there is console warnings, most probably related: [Presentation] Presenting view controller <_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x160206000> from detached view controller <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerVS_14_ViewList_View_: 0x15ae209f0> is discouraged.

Comment: Thanks, will submit it soon.

Comment: Please post the Radar # when you file the bug.

Comment: Here is the radar id: #FB9816860

Answer (score 4):

Apple/SwiftUI doesn't want to have Tabs enclosed in a NavigationView, because the Tabs should always be visible:

> Avoid hiding the tab bar when people navigate to different areas in
> your app. The tab bar is a global navigation control for your app, so
> make sure it’s always visible.
> https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/tab-bars/

If you don't want this, why not use custom "Tabs" in the bottom at your start page?

```
@main
struct SmallApplication: App {
    
    @State private var tabSelector = 1
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                
                Group {
                    if tabSelector == 1 {
                        TabbedView1()
                    } else {
                        TabbedView2()
                    }
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                        Button {
                            tabSelector = 1
                        } label: {
                            Label("Tab1", systemImage: "scanner")
                        }
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                        Button {
                            tabSelector = 2
                        } label: {
                            Label("Tab2", systemImage: "person")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your issue. I have created two NavigationViews, one for each tab. See code below.

```
struct SmallApplication: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            
                TabView {
                    NavigationView {
                        TabbedView1()}
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Tab1", systemImage: "scanner")
                        }
                    
                    NavigationView {
                        TabbedView2()}
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Tab2", systemImage: "person")
                        }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello  and thanks for the answer.Much appreciated .This is not an option, because I want to have bottom bar hidden when navigating. This happen only with one navigation bar

Comment: I see what you mean. Good luck, cheers!