# SwiftUI NavigationLink destination in TabView will be dismissed after background scene phase

Tags: swiftui

In the "Dest" view, after my app going to background mode and coming back to foreground mode, the navigation destination is dismissed automatically. How can I prevent this? Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      TabView {
        NavigationLink {Text("Dest")} label: {Text("go to dest")}.tabItem {Text("c1")}
        Text("a2").tabItem {Text("c2")}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `NavigationView` inside the `TabView`:

```
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        NavigationView { // here
            NavigationLink() {
                Text("Dest")
            } label: {
                Text("go to dest")
            }
        }
        .tabItem {Text("c1")}
        
        Text("a2")
            .tabItem {Text("c2")}
    }
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't fit my requirement. Because I Don't want the Destination View with the TabView Bar at the bottom.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70434302/swiftui-sheet-presented-from-tab-view-pops-to-root-view-of-a-tab/70833865#70833865